# Ruby on Rails: Fixtures without Database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-plugins, fixtures

I'm working on a 2-phase RoR project where in the first phase we are going to have alot of static data and in the second phase this will be dynamic.  I'm fairly new to RoR and thought that for the first phase rather than have hard-coded arrays I could leverage fixtures for the first phase and then in the second we could just pull the curtains away and we have the first steps of putting the database in.

My problem is I can't seem to find a way to use fixtures directly, that is in not using the fixtures to pre-populate a database.  I  want to basically be able to call the models just like I would if there was data and it return the fixtures.

I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Would [factory_girl](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl) work for you?